# Does Spring still only supports method execution join points?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I know that Spring used to support only method execution join points as stated in documents of release [2.0.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html) :

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans)

I can't find any comments on the current capabilities of Spring AOP join points in the latest [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same for latest version. [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-defn)

In 5.1. AOP Concepts, second points:

> In Spring AOP, a join point always represents a method execution.